# How to derive a matrix form of quadratic equation using Sympy or other

Tags: python, math, scipy, sympy, sage

Is there a way to convert that? For example from this equation:

[image]

To this matrix form:

[image]

We especially would like to get thos matrices circled-red.

This is the code I have at the moment:

```
from sympy import *
x, y = symbols('x y')
expr = 0.5 * (x**2) + 3*x + 4*y
print(latex(expr))
```

I welcome suggestion other than Simpy (no MATLAB please).

At the end of the day I'd like to use it with [CVXOPT](http://cvxopt.org/index.html) or Scipy.

Answer (score 3):

I can't give you any python code, but I can explain how to derive the matrices and the vector:

Your form is:

```
                     T                           T
f(x, y) = 1/2 * | x |  * | a  b | * | x | + | d |  * | x |
                | y |    | b  c |   | y |   | e |    | y |
```

This is equal to:

```
f(x, y) = 1/2 * a x^2 + b * xy + 1/2 * c y^2 + d x + e y
```

So you just need to put the coefficients at the correct positions in the matrix form (`a = 2 * coefficient of x^2, b = coefficient of xy, etc.`).